# Declaring an object of a subclass when the base class is abstract

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I am learning about virtual functions and abstract classes and it seems that I have a difficulty in comprehending something. Let's say I have this code:

```
class animal {
  public:
    virtual void show()=0;
};

class dog : public animal {
  int weight;
};


int main()
{
  //animal a;
  dog d;
  return 0;
};
```

I understand how animal a is incorrect because the animal class is abstract and I am not allowed to declare objects of this class. However, why the dog d is also incorrect? (given that the class dog is not abstract and so I can declare dog objects)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Because you didn't override `show` so `dog` is also abstract

Comment: *"given that the class dog is not abstract and so I can declare dog objects"* This is an incorrect assumption. `dog` also has an pure virtual `show()` inherited from `animal`.

Comment: Ok I overrode show and everything is going well. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derived class `Dog` is also an abstract class because the pure virtual function `show` is not overridden. So the class `Dog` has the same pure virtual function.

Take into account that if you need the polymorphism then you have to declare the destructor of the base class as virtual.

At least you can write

```
class animal {
  public:
    virtual ~animal() = default;
    virtual void show()=0;
};
```

Comment: Note that having a virtual destructor is not *required* but *highly recommended* in the example given. You don't need a virtual destructor unless you are planning on destroying derived objects by calling `delete` on base class pointers, in which case virtual dispatch is needed to make sure all derived destructors are called. That is not the case in this example.

Answer (score 0):

The important concept here that you are missing is that your abstract class, `animal`, has what is called a **pure virtual function**, which in your case, is

```
virtual void show()=0;
```

Normally, overriding a virtual function is optional. In your case, because you have declared your virtual function as **pure** by adding `=0` to the end, the C++ compiler requires you to override `show()` in all classes that inherit from `animal`, such as `dog`.

To make your `dog` class non-abstract and compliant with your `animal` interface, add a function definition for `show()` in `dog`, so that the compiler can successfully link its parent's pure virtual function. That would look something like this:

```
class dog : public animal {
 inline void show()
    { //something here
      return;
    };
  int weight;
};
```

Comment: we don't normally use the `inline` keyword when the function is defined within the class definition.

Comment: Is there another way to make the function `inline`d when the definition is in the class definition? I guess I don't follow

Comment: @alteredinstance -- a function that's defined inside the class definition is inline. That's why you don't need to say it.